# Order By property from dynamic linq

Tags: linq, dynamic, properties, sql-order-by

I am using dynamic linq to make a generic class for processing a generic JqGrid from MVC all works fine (searching, pagination etc) except for sorting on code properties.  Sorting works fine when I am hitting the DB to sort the data, but as soon as it is a property I have made the sorting does not work eg

```
 public partial class tblStockOrder
{
    public string approved
    {
        get
        {
            return approved_id == null ? "" : "Approved";
        }
    }
}
```

I am running the following Dynamic Linq

```
        items = items
            .OrderBy(string.Format("{0} {1}", sidx, sord))
            .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize);
```

Where sidx etc are strings passed in by jquery.

So basically what is the best solution for handling a case where some properties will be from the db while others will be code properties (not sure of the correct naming).  I can handle all this in code using reflection but would obviously like the DB to handle as much of the searching / sorting as possible without pulling in thousands of records and sorting through them in code using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Computed class will of course not work, as you're trying to create record which is part in memory, part in database.

You can, however, compute the same on database by specifying the function in linq query, example:
items = items
            .OrderBy(x=> x.approved_id != null )
            .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize);